# How to increase the current in a lemon battery?

Tags: electric-current, batteries, electrochemistry

I tried to make the classic lemon battery today and ran into a bit of trouble.

I used 4 large tennis ball sized lemons with copper and zinc galvanized nails for electrodes.

I connected the 4 lemons in series and a voltmeter gave a reading of 3.5 V so I'm confident that my set-up is correct.

Just to be clear I connected the copper nail from one lemon to the zinc nail of a different lemon. I used copper wire and crocodile clips.

I tried to light a 3 V LED with no success. I tried the LED in both directions to be sure and a 1.5 V, 3.0 and 6.0 V battery all lit up the LED so the LED is not faulty.

The current read zero in the circuit. Why is this? How do I increase the current in this circuit? I tried massaging the lemons to make them more juicy.

I just can't figure it out. On the internet there are lots of pictures of just one or two lemons lighting an LED. I bought 4 more lemons which I will add to the series tomorrow but the current was zero so I'm not hopeful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Increase current capacity of a battery by increasing the surface area of the electrodes. (i.e., instead of one copper and one zinc nail, use two of each, with the two copper nails electrically connected to each other, and the two zinc nails connected to each other.) But, out of curiosity, did you check to make sure you hooked up the LED with the correct polarity? The "D" in LED stands for [_diode_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode).

Answer (score 1):

The current-producing character of a battery is in general set by the surface area of its electrodes.  Try using 1/2" wide strips of copper and zinc metal instead of nails, and remember: throw away the lemons when done!